# Azure Pipelines fails to resolve dependency even through artifact is available in Azure Feed

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

My Azure Pipeline build fails with the following errror:

> Failed to collect dependencies at
> org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1: Failed to read artifact
> descriptor for org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1: Could not
> transfer artifact org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:pom:3.8.1 from/to
> SDC_MvnRepo
> (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXX/XXX/_packaging/SDC_MvnRepo/maven/v1):
> Transfer failed for
> https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXX/XXX/_packaging/SDC_MvnRepo/maven/v1/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1/commons-lang3-3.8.1.pom:
> Connection reset -> [Help 1]

However if I copy and paste the url for the pom it downloads fine to my local machine.

Pipeline is being built by Project Collection Service Accounts. I have added it as a Contributor to the feed. Build still fails with the same message:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2  to my maven command in the Azure Pipeline build. Logs really didn't indicate the true issue

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it seems that the current service account doesn't have the permission to cache the packages from org.apache.commons to your local feed.

Please make sure, the service account has the write permission to cache the packages to your Azure feed. Basically, please check the role settings for your service account, at least set the `contributor` role in `SDC_MvnRepo` feed.

By default Maven’s local repository is configured to be `${user.home}/.m2/repository`.

Comment: Hello, I've updated my original question with more pictures. I've added the Default Agent Pool Owner account to the feed's permissions and the build still fails.